# Qt 5.3.1: macdeployqt tries to include everything on my hard drive; how to fix?

Tags: macos, qt, qt5, macdeployqt

I'm running Qt 5.3.1 on Mac OS X 10.8 and 10.9 I'm trying to use the macdeployqt tool to bundle libraries and plugins with my executable, but it's apparently trying to include everything on my hard drive.

I invoke it with:

```
/Applications/Qt/5.3.1/5.3/clang_64/bin/macdeployqt /Users/adamwilt/Desktop/temp/DesktopPixie.app -verbose=2
-qmldir=/Users/adamwilt/Desktop/temp/DesktopPixie.app/Contents/Resources/qml/DesktopPixie
```

and get lots of normal, expected log messages like:

```
Log: copy: "/Applications/Qt/5.3.1/5.3/clang_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Base/images" "/Users/adamwilt/Desktop/temp/DesktopPixie.app/Contents/Resources/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Base/images"
```

...and all runs fine until I start getting messages like:

```
Log: copy: "" "/Users/adamwilt/Desktop/temp/DesktopPixie.app/Contents/Resources/qml/MessageBoxUI/Enums"
ERROR: file copy failed from "/do-gst"
ERROR:  to "/Users/adamwilt/Desktop/temp/DesktopPixie.app/Contents/Resources/qml/MessageBoxUI/Enums/do-gst"
ERROR: file copy failed from "/rescuepro.properties"
ERROR:  to "/Users/adamwilt/Desktop/temp/DesktopPixie.app/Contents/Resources/qml/MessageBoxUI/Enums/rescuepro.properties"
ERROR: file copy failed from "/rescuepro34act.lic"
```

and then the fun begins:

```
Log: copy: "/Applications" "/Users/adamwilt/Desktop/temp/DesktopPixie.app/Contents/Resources/qml/MessageBoxUI/Enums/Applications"
Log:  copied: "/Applications/License.rtf"
Log:  to "/Users/adamwilt/Desktop/temp/DesktopPixie.app/Contents/Resources/qml/MessageBoxUI/Enums/Applications/License.rtf"
Log: copy: "/Applications/0xED-1.0.7.app" "/Users/adamwilt/Desktop/temp/DesktopPixie.app/Contents/Resources/qml/MessageBoxUI/Enums/Applications/0xED-1.0.7.app"
```

It appears it's trying to copy everything (that is, "") into the app, but I ^C out of it while I still have disk space left!

It didn't do this at first; then it did so for a week; then it stopped; now it's back. This is a distributed development project; I'm doing the QML stuff and folks elsewhere are doing the C++. It's possible the other folks are changing a configuration somewhere that's causing this to occur, but I'm the only one doing Mac deployments, so I'm the only one who sees this.

Is there a config file of some sort for macdeployqt where this might be getting triggered? Or is it more likely a problem related to the C++ object MessageBoxUI, which defines several Q_ENUMs (apparently correctly, as it compiles without warnings or errors, and appears to run properly), since that's the target directory when it starts going mad?

Answer (score 1):

Sussed it (well enough that I can go on):

The Qt app I'm trying to deploy lives in ~/Desktop/temp. If I set my current directory to ~/Desktop or ~/Desktop/temp before I run macdeployqt, it runs as expected.

If I run it from from my home directory ~, or ~/Documents, macdeployqt tries to pull in everything it finds in /Applications, /opt, and/or other directories unassociated with the app.

Setting cwd to most other paths, including ~/Downloads, /Applications, subdirectories of ~/Documents, etc. also seems to work; it's only running macdeployqt from ~ and ~/Documents that causes the problem.

No proper explanation as to *why* this is happening, but just a warning **in case someone else sees this sort of weird behavior: try changing to the apps's location before running macdeployqt.**